# Is there a way to only install certain modules of this pod?

Tags: cosmicmind

We're trying to cut down on the amount of pods that we're using for our xCode project for optimisation purposes. We use Cocoapods to install Material & Motion, however, we only ever use the TextField module within the Material pod.

Is there a way that we could designate only the TextField module for installation in order to save on project size and build time?
I understand that the module has a lot of dependencies within Material & Motion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be in Material 3, which launches in January 2018.

Comment: Is Material 3 still scheduled for release this month?

Comment: At least the initial release of it is, and throughout February more components will make there way into the framework :)

Comment: I'm guessing the release got delayed?

Comment: New components have been entering, but no release. It will be very soon. Apologies on the delay.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the update again - I know that these things can take a long time

Comment: @CosmicMind has this been added to the latest build

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta not yet. We are working on it, but other features have been a higher priority. Thank you for checking in.

Comment: @CosmicMind any update on this?